# Unusual Android error

Tags: android

I have an Activity that uses a ListView to simply display a list of options for a user to select and when they select an option they are taken to a new Activity.

However on occasion the Activity with the options freezes when I try to select one of the options, I get the ANR and in the log cat the following error is displayed:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing pause of activity that is not resumed:<Activity>
```

Does anyone know what this error means and how to diagnose it?

A search brings up very little.

Does anyone know what may be causing the error?

I can post the code on request

**Code as requested:**

```
lvMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

            switch(position){

            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsApp.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case 1:
                Intent intentHO = new Intent(.this, SettingsHO.class);
                startActivity(intentHO);
                break;
            case 2:
                Intent intentWifi = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
                startActivity(intentWifi);
                break;
            case 3:
                Intent intentAudio = new Intent(this, SettingsAudio.class);
                startActivity(intentAudio);
                break;
            case 4:
                Intent intentDiagnostics = new Intent(this, PhoneStatus.class);
                startActivity(intentDiagnostics);

            }

        }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem you're doing something wrong starting a new Activity. Please post your onClickListener method.

Comment: Can you tell what was the problem?